# SQL Server BCP Command giving me difficulty

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

All,

I have this program that runs the `BCP` command.  Both run off the same machine but different databases on that machine.  This is my machine.  The error that I get is right below.  I only get that error in `ColoColoStage` but not in `ColoRepo`.

I am trying to tweak and make the change needed for this error to not happen in `ColoRepoStage`.  Could anyone help me?  I will say that the `E1_CSV_Final_2` table exists in both databases and it consists of just one field.  Just to test this I ran select queries against both of them.  I guess this might be a permissions issue.

> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'ColorepoStage.dbo.E1_CSV_Final_2'.

- Code that fails

```
'bcp "select [Field] from [ColorepoStage].[dbo].[E1_CSV_Final_2]"

 - Code that works

'bcp "select [Field] from [Colorepo].[dbo].[E1_CSV_Final_2]"
```

[image: Both Databases on my machine]

[image: Additional SQL Server Database Layout]

Comment: Not sure how much more clear that error message could be. You don't have an object with that name in the ColorepoStage database.

Comment: Sean I do though because if I run the below query in another window it runs perfectly "select [Field] from [colorepostage].[dbo].[E1_CSV_Final_2]"

Comment: ColoColoStage, ColoRepo, ColoRepoStage - three different names but you mention two databases. Nor do we know what "i have this program" refers to. Your image appears to show two different database instances - so perhaps you are confused about which instance your command is connected to when executing.

Comment: How are you calling BCP? From command line? From SSIS package? From xp_cmdshell? From within a compiled app? Also, when you get the error, what "machine" are you running on? Is "your machine" a local desktop installation of SQL Server or are you connecting to a distributed server on separate hardware?

Comment: Also, if you can confirm that the bcp commands you've shared is EXACTLY how they are being called (with no server option... no use of -S option) then I think I know what your issue is.

Comment: Jamie thanks so much.  But Yes this is a local desktop installation of SQL Server.  Also here is the actual command that works in one database

Comment: 'bcp "select [Field] from [colorepo].[dbo].[E1_CSV_Final_2]" queryout "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\HDR_XML_GEN\'

Comment: how are you calling that command? in SSMS query window using xp_cmdshell? from DOS command prompt? SSIS package, etc... how? How about when it fails?

Comment: SET atSQLSTRING = atSQLSTRING + atFileString
 
 EXEC xp_cmdshell atSQLSTRING

Comment: I used the "at" FYI instead of @ because this site will not enable me to use @ as it expects me to be referencing a user

Comment: So the one that fails is --SET @SQLSTRING = 'bcp "select [Field] from [ColorepoStage].[dbo].[E1_CSV_Final]" queryout "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\HDR_XML_GEN\'

Comment: The only difference is the database being referenced and it states the object is not found but I can totally run select [Field] from [ColorepoStage].[dbo].[E1_CSV_Final] with zero issues because the object does exist.  I think this is something about the object existing but BCP can not find it perhaps.  I need to maybe more explicitly point out the database maybe?

Comment: Lastly yes Jamie.  I am calling it from the SSMS query window using xp_cmdshell

Comment: okay, I added an answer below. Your symptoms are very familiar, so my guess is below. Just to be sure, confirm the server your query window is connected to. The query window shows the sql server connected to on the window edge at the bottom of the window. you see your local server name? do you have more than one instance installed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203766/discussion-between-jamie-and-jp3nyc).

Answer (score 0):

Without having to interrogate with too many more questions, you should give this a try. Usually when I see this question/issue it has to do with how you are calling BCP; specifically with how you do not include the -S option.

When you leave out the -S option, BCP trys to determine which server you want to connect to. This should be the local, primary installation to where the command is being executed from. As you are issuing a "xp_cmdshell" sql command to call BCP from... BCP should be asking your local machine for a SQL Server, primary installation.

It's possible you have more than one instance installed?
Or BCP is 'somehow' finding some other instance of SQL to connect to (which does not have the object you can see is there).

So essentially BCP is not connecting to the instance of SQL Server that you think it is.
Try adding the -S option to your command and see if that works.Force BCP to use the server you want, do not let it try to figure that out.

Comment: Argh.. I wish that were the case but it appears I am already using the S option no?

Comment: SET ATFileString = ATFileName + '.csv" -S 10.88.0.130 -T -c -t,'
 SET ATSQLSTRING = 'bcp "select [Field] from [ColorepoStage].[dbo].[E1_CSV_Final]" queryout "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\HDR_XML_GEN\'
 SET ATSQLSTRING = ATSQLSTRING + ATFileString
 
 EXEC xp_cmdshell ATSQLSTRING

Comment: SET ATFileString = ATFileName + '.csv" -S 10.88.0.130 -T -c -t,'

 SET ATSQLSTRING = 'bcp "select [Field] from [ColorepoStage].[dbo].[E1_CSV_Final]" queryout "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\HDR_XML_GEN\'

 SET ATSQLSTRING = ATSQLSTRING + ATFileString
 
 EXEC xp_cmdshell ATSQLSTRING

Comment: Jamie, also take a look at the picture I added.  FYI.  You are an incredible help if I resolve this matter or not.  Thank you VERY much

Comment: go to chat. too many comments here :) chat link is in above comments

Comment: Jamie, ultimately I found the reason but it was because you continuously pointed me in the right direction.  Thank you!

Comment: if you would, please include how your resolved :) that is the nature of the site.